# Force ASP .Net Web API to block HTTP requests with Error (403)

Tags: rest, ssl, asp.net-web-api, iis-10

I would like to configure my project to not allow http requests with the following restrictions:

1. It must be a global restriction for all APIs (via web.config, script in the installer, etc.)
2. It must be hard coded(not pressing "Require SSL" on the APP in the IIS)
3. No "redirect"- just return error (403)

my ideal option would be to configure "Require SSL" by a script which runs in the installer.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is working or not working?

Comment: global action filter that inspects scheme of incoming requests and returns 403 if not https.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by writing a simple `ActionFilter` that inspects the request and responds when the scheme is not set to ssl.  A very minimal implementation may look something like:

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
}
```

To make this apply everywhere, you'll likely want to register it as a global filter in the WebAPI configuration when your application is bootstrapping.  That would look something like:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

        // ... More configuration ...
    }
}
```

If you search the web a bit, you can find many examples of similar filters with more robust logic that may better meet your needs.